# Error editing files through web interface when running web2py from source - what am I missing?

Tags: python, web2py

I have tried cloning the web2py git repo on both Mint, and Fedora, and in both cases, I get the same thing: it works great, except after logging into the web interface as admin, if I go to edit any python files through the web interface (ex. examples/controllers/default.py), I get a web page with a popup: "An error occured, please reload the page". Reloading the page does the same thing.

Am I missing some dependencies? python-tk is optional, and doesn't help. I also tried installing python-web2py from the Mint repos, hoping the repo version and the github version had the same dependencies that apt would install automatically. The repo version is clearly older - it's interface is very different, and it is able to edit files through the web without a problem. The git version still has the same problem however. Are there other dependencies the latest git version of web2py needs? JRE?

Comment: 1) Linux is Linux, so not sure what you expected Fedora to fix over Mint 2) Python is not Java, so why do you need the JRE? Anyways, maybe you could provide a [mcve] instead of just saying it doesn't work

Comment: If "Linux is Linux" was true, there would only be one distribution. Different software gets packaged with different distributions. If something doesn't work, trying a different distribution, seeing it work, and figuring out the difference is a perfectly acceptable troubleshooting strategy, especially if you already have both distros installed. Python is not HTML either, but I'm guessing if your browser didn't support HTML, web2py wouldn't work... And I did provide a minimal example that doesn't work for me - clone web2py github repo, run, try to edit file through web interface.

Comment: Fair enough, but cloning a git repo into either flavor of Unix shouldn't make a difference was my main point

Comment: Also, you should at least get some stacktrace in the terminal or the Javascript console for an internal server error

Comment: Javascript was a guess at a dependency I might be missing that I was hoping someone might confirm - I don't actually know if it uses javascript to edit files through the web interface. I also see no exceptions, or errors in my terminal when running the web2py web server through the terminal, and trying to edit a file through the web. "An error occured, please reload the page" is the only error I see anywhere, and it's not very specific.

Comment: Javascript is built into the engine of the browser, so nothing is needed for it to work other than that. Editing a file sounds like something that would require it though, since that's a dynamic action

Comment: Also installed chromium, and tried it there, in case the problem was something browser-specific. Still exactly the same error. Any chance I'm missing something obvious, or should I be filing a bug report?

Comment: I'm not in a place to try to reproduce the problem, so a Github issue might be the recommended approach. I'm also not able to find a examples/controllers/default.py file in the repository

Comment: web2py/applications/examples/controllers/default.py, but that was just an example of a file I couldn't edit - I can view the source code of all files through the web interface without a problem, but I can't edit any file through the web interface. Editing files with vi obviously works fine thought. I might go ahead and start a github issue in that case - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started an issue about it [here](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/issues/1337).

Turns out this was some bug that will likely be fixed by the time the next version of web2py comes out.